# How to replace dynamic cursor for better performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, cursor, query-optimization

It is hard to find maximum value to loop inside dynamic query to replace Cursor. I want to replace dynamic cursor for better performance .please help

```
set @sql='declare TsmArrray cursor for select * '  
select @sql= CASE when @IncludeAllLangField = 0 then @sql+'from 
IADL_GENDataColumn where otherarray not like '+CHAR(39)+'%.%'+CHAR(39)+' or 
otherarray like '+CHAR(39)+'%.eng'+CHAR(39)+' order by otherarray'  
else @sql+'from IADL_GENDataColumn order by  CASE WHEN otherarray not like 
'+CHAR(39)+'%.%'+CHAR(39)+' or otherarray like '+CHAR(39)+'%.eng'+CHAR(39)+' 
then 1 else 2 end, otherarray' end   
exec (@sql)  

open TsmArrray  
FETCH NEXT FROM TsmArrray into  @colname, @coltyp  
While (@@Fetch_status = 0)  
BEGIN
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh : SQL SERVER

Comment: Why are you using dynamic sql here in the first place? And why do you think you need a cursor? This is just a wall of text query that is nearly impossible to decipher.

Comment: @SeanLange please help me to re-build .i am trying to find maximum value to loop .

Comment: You are going about this the wrong way. You want to avoid loops, not use crazy dynamic sql to build them. I can't help you because I am not going to spend the time needed to unravel that mess above into something legible. You probably need to rethink your approach here completely. I would be willing to help with that but I need some details. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.